# PostgreSQL json_build_object return bad result

Tags: postgresql

I'm a beginner with PostgreSQL Query request and i have a problem.

I made a request to return a JSON object like this

```
select 
json_build_object(
    'id', u.id,
    ...
)
from test u
```

And my request contains some left join. The problem is in my result, it return me that

```
[
{
 json_build_object : {My object}
}
]
```

My entire query looks like this

```
select 
json_build_object(
    'id', u.id,
    'created_at', u.created_at,
    'updated_at', u.updated_at,
    'siren', u.siren,
    'personnes_morale', json_build_object(
        'denomination', pm.denomination,
        'devise', pm.devise
    ),
    'personne_physique', json_build_object(
        'created_at', pp.created_at,
        'updated_at', pp.updated_at,
        'siren', pp.siren
    ),
    'representants', json_agg(json_build_object(
        'qualite', r.qualite,
        'nationalite', r.nationalite
    ))
    )
from dossiers_entreprises u

left join personnes_morales pm on pm.siren = u.siren
left join personnes_physiques pp on pp.siren = u.siren
left join representants r on r.siren = u.siren
where u.siren = '428208276'
group by u.id, pm.denomination,  pm.devise, pp.libelle_derniere_modification, pp.created_at, pp.updated_at, pp.siren
limit 1;
```

(i've delete some data in group by and in the select, because there is a lot of datas to get)

Data looks like this :

dossiers_entreprise :

| --- | id | siren |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 12345 |
| 2 | 213 | 32564 |

personnes_morales :

| --- | denomination |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Jesse |

personnes_physique :

| --- | siren |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 |
| 2 | 32564 |

representants :

| --- | qualite | nationalite |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | France |
| 2 | 32564 | France |

The result of this actual query looks like this

```
[
  {
    json_build_object: {
      id: 'b65af895-47e0-4c5d-978b-b4c322da857d',
      created_at: '2020-12-14T15:29:46.968884',
      updated_at: '2020-12-14T15:29:46.968884',
      siren: '428208276',
      personnes_morale: [Object],
      personne_physique: [Object],
      representants: [Array]
    }
  }
]
```

The result that i want

```
[
  {
      id: 'b65af895-47e0-4c5d-978b-b4c322da857d',
      created_at: '2020-12-14T15:29:46.968884',
      updated_at: '2020-12-14T15:29:46.968884',
      siren: '428208276',
      personnes_morale: [Object],
      personne_physique: [Object],
      representants: [Array]
    }
]
```

PS : my nodeJS script looks like this :

```
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'xxxx',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  database: 'xxxx',
  password: 'xxxx',
  port: 5432,
})
pool.query("select json_build_object('id', u.id,'created_at', u.created_at,'updated_at', u.updated_at,'siren', u.siren,'personnes_morale', json_build_object('denomination', pm.denomination,'devise', pm.devise),'personne_physique', json_build_object('created_at', pp.created_at,'updated_at', pp.updated_at,'siren', pp.siren),    'representants', json_agg(json_build_object('qualite', r.qualite,'nationalite', r.nationalite))) from dossiers_entreprises u left join personnes_morales pm on pm.siren = u.siren left join personnes_physiques pp on pp.siren = u.siren left join representants r on r.siren = u.siren where u.siren = '428208276' group by u.id, pm.denomination,  pm.devise, pp.libelle_derniere_modification, pp.created_at, pp.updated_at, pp.siren limit 1;", (err, res) => {

  console.log(res.rows)
  pool.end()
})
```

Is it possible to get my result without those "json_build_object" objects and have my object directly in the array ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That looks strange. Please show us some sample data and the entire query

Comment: Please show us the **complete** query you are using. As written, that query will not return an array, nor will it use `jsonb_build_object` as the key name

Comment: I've update my question with my datas

When i get result by a nodejs script, it returns me an array. And when i export from software (like TablePlus) it gives me an array too

Comment: Rather than `json_build_object : {My object}` can you show us _the actual result_ for the sample data you've included? It's not at all clear if the same object is being repeated, or it's being split into multiple parts, or what. See also the help page on creating a [mcve] and [this discussion of how that relates to SQL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: I've add the actual result and my nodeJS script

Comment: The `json_build_object` key name in the result can easily be fixed by using a column alias `select json_build_object(.....) as object from ...`. The array in the result is apparently generated by the code that retrieves (or displays) the result, it's certainly not a consequence of the `jsonb_build_object()` call

Comment: The problem is not the array, the problem is the `json_build_object` key. I would like to delete it and only have the requested object in the array. But if it's not possible, i will deal with it in y nodeJS script

Comment: I think `json_build_object` is my result header. So i should find how return result without header